# Bootstrap image carousel, with text to the right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Okay, so I'm trying to get a webpage to show a [Bootstrap image carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), which works! But I want some text to the right of it. I'm not trying to get the text to change with the image, just be to the side.

Here is the HTML for the page;
http://pastebin.com/EabGfv3H#

And here is the custom CSS I'm using;
http://pastebin.com/MEtF1hTR

And a JSFiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/3942/

Needed code for JSFiddle link, so here is the html;

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li> 
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/Beaches and Villages\Golden Beach umbrellas home.JPG" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Golden Beach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Beaches and Villages\Limenas ancient city.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Limenas
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/Beaches and Villages\Potos sunset.JPG" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Potos
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div id="carousel_text" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
            <p>
                Thasos, an island surrounded by the crystal-clear emerald waters of the Aegean Sea is part of the Northeastern islands of 
                Greece, also being the closest one to the continent. It is the perfect getaway for holidays during summer, a place where 
                you can relax and enjoy your holidays, forget about all your worries on a quiet sandy beach, but also a place where you 
                can explore the Greek way of life, try the best foods and meet the most amazing people.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried not using the bootstrap columns and just using float left and right, which didn't work.

Comment: Can you add an image mockup showing how exactly you want it? The jsFiddle seems not executing your code in required way.

Comment: Here is the image mockup; http://imgur.com/a/4OPl5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your image mockup, I assume you need the carousel on some 75% width while the other text/div on remaining 25% width within your main container. OR the text/div should be outside of carousel.

So if that's the case, try using this -

1. add a new class `carousel-left` to `<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-left" data-ride="carousel">`
2. add/update your text-div in html as shown below:

```html
<div class="bs-example" data-example-id="simple-carousel">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-left" data-ride="carousel">...</div>

  <div class="some-text">your text div</div>
</div>
```

3. add following in your css -

`.carousel-left { width: 75%; float: left; }`

`.some-text { float: left; width: 25%; }`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Had to remove the 'row' and 'col-md-12' divs as well to get this to work. I know you don't have them, just adding for anyone else who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I add `pull-left` class to img, and add `pull-right` class to your text and place it inside `<span>` not `<div>` and remove `carousel-caption` from it.seems to work [Pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfqzQgO3hzscR5nFoPuL)

```
<div class="item">
      <img class="pull-left" src="images/Beaches and Villages\Limenas ancient city.jpg" alt="...">
      <span class="pull-right">
           Limenas
      </span>
</div>
```